# How to iterate over the elements of a tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have coded a neural network that returns a list of 3 numbers for every input sample. These values are then subtracted from the actual values to get the difference.

For example,

```
actual    = [1,2,3]  
predicted = [0,0,1]  
diff      = [1,2,2]
```

So my tensor now has the shape [batch_size, 3]
What I want to do is to iterate over the tensor elements to construct my loss function.
For instance, if my batch_size is 2 and finally

```
diff = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
```

I want the loss to be

```
Loss = mean(sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2), sqrt(d^2+e^2+f^2))
```

I know that TensorFlow has a [tf.nn.l2_loss()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) function that computes the L2 loss of the entire tensor. But what I want is the mean of l2 losses of elements of a tensor along some axis.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: here's a pro tip, build your loss function on dummy data using numpy functions like np.mean, np.sum, etc, with axis argument to operate over batches, eg: np.mean(array, axis=1). Then swap for the equivalent tensorflow functions as in Franck's answer.

Comment: Will keep in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`tf.sqrt`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sqrt) followed by  [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum) and  [`tf.reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean). Both `tf.reduce_sum` and `tf.reduce_mean` have an `axis` argument that indicates which dimensions to reduce.

For more reduction operations, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/math_ops#Reduction

Comment: This was rather easy. Thanks!